# Is there a way in Visual Studio 2022 to compare a Branch to its Base without having to find the commit it was Derived from?

Tags: git, compare, branch, visual-studio-2022

Suppose I have a branch called `Development` and from that I derive the branch `Items/Feature_A`.  I work on `Feature_A` making several commits.  `Development` then has several commits made to it from other branches.  I now want to see the difference between the latest commit in `Feature_A` and the point from which it was derived from on `Development` - is there a way to do this without having to find/guess the commit on `Development`?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and was hoping there would be a feature similar to how you can now select a branch, bring up the branch menu, right click on another branch and select "Compare with Current Branch...", only I was hoping to find a "Compare with Base..." if I did this on the branch I'm already on.

Answer (score 1):

from the command line, that would be :

```
git diff Development...Feature_A  # <- three dots
# or:
git diff Development...HEAD       # <- if Feature_A is your active branch
# or:
git diff Development...           # <- short for 'Development...HEAD'
```

I don't know about Visual Studio and its GUI, if you have a way to type the string which is passed to `git diff` in one of your GUI's fields, you can type `Development...`

Comment: Is the `...` what is making GIT compare `Feature_A` to the commit from which it was derived from `Development` rather than the latest commit on `Development`?

Comment: @MattArnold: yes. See [git help diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), near the end of the [Description section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1)